# I can't change the project font using an external font

Tags: react-native

I am trying to use an external font in a project. Already configured the file "react-native-config", already added the font, already made the link, but when I set fontFamily, does not work. Does anyone know how to solve?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Share to us ur .env.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ios, you can add this code at the begining of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in `AppDelegate` to check whether your font is installed or not

```
    NSArray *fontFamilies = [UIFont familyNames];
    for (int i = 0; i < [fontFamilies count]; i++)
    {
      NSString *fontFamily = [fontFamilies objectAtIndex:i];
      NSArray *fontNames = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:[fontFamilies objectAtIndex:i]];
      NSLog (@"%@: %@", fontFamily, fontNames);
    }
```

If you are using Android, you have to add font weight at the end

```
fontFamily: "Montserrat-Regular"

or

fontFamily: "Montserrat-Bold"
```